# Direct formula for sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, functions, generating-functions

I want to find out the function to generate the sequence with the following pattern.
`1 2 3 1 1 2 2 3 3 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 3` ....
Where the lower bound number is 1 upper number bound number is 3. Each time numbers start from 1 and each number repeats `2 ^` n times, with n starting with 0.

Comment: Naming the terms of your sequence $a_n$.  Are you looking for a function $f$ such that $f(n)=a_n$? Or are you looking for a closed form of the generating function $F(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n x^n$?

Comment: The function can return only number k such that k is from 1 to 3. Given that our input is n > 0.

Comment: @ArtyomAbrahamyan Please delete the question from here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3554719/sequence-of-repeating-numbers?fbclid=IwAR0SrHxvVlgHQacxY7ETyC7K-p6NTMp-gYHYarrKFOm__qYmHSqiLxjFZJM

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following [PARI/GP](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/) code will do what you want

```
a(n) = (n-3*2^(k=exponent((n-1)\3+1))+2)\2^k+1;
```

Note that `exponent(n)` is the binary exponent of $n$. In other words, the floor of the base $2$ logarithm of $n$. Also, `n\m` is the floor of $n/m$. Here is an example of use of the code:

```
? vector(45,n,a(n))
[1,2,3,1,1,2,2,3,3,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3]
```

The logic is not hard. We need $\lfloor\log_2(n)\rfloor+1$ for something like $[1,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,5,\dots]$. Because we repeat 3 times in each cycle we need to replace $n$ with something like $\lfloor n/3\rfloor$. The actual number we need is
 $$k = \lfloor\log_2(\lfloor (n-1)/3\rfloor +1)\rfloor. $$ This ensures that
$\, 0 \le n - 3\cdot 2^k +2 < 3\cdot 2^k .\,$ Note that
 $\, 1 \le (n - 3\cdot 2^k + 2)/2^k + 1 < 4.$
which is what we want.

Comment: Thank you for answer. Can you please elaborate on the logic behind this.

Answer (score 2):

Im not sure if you want a closed form solution or not.  The following solution is programmable with while loops

Let
$$ 1,2,3,1,1,2,2,3,3,...=a_1 , a_2, a_3, a_4, ... $$
Define $n_0 = 0$ to be the initiation of the sequence.  The sequence resets to $1$ every so often (for example, it resets at position $4$, then again at position $10$). The $k^{th}$ reset, $k \geq 1$ occurs at position 
$$n_k = 1+3 \sum_{j=0}^{k-1}2^j$$
The length of the patterns also get bigger.  The $k^{th}$ iteration of the pattern is of length $\ell_k = 3 (2^k)$ for $k\geq 0$.

Then we can define 2 functions.  The first function $f(n)$ identifies *which* iteration of the pattern we are in:
$$ f(n) = \min\{ k : n_{k} \leq n < n_{k+1} \}  $$
And the second function $g(x)$ is what you want. It decides *where* in the iteration we are (if we are in the first third of the iteration, return 1.  If in the second, return 2, if in the third return 3):
$$ g(n) = 
\begin{cases}
1 & \mbox{ if }\,\, 0 \leq \frac{n - n_{f(n)}}{\ell_{f(k)}} < \frac{1}{3} \\
2 & \mbox{ if }\,\, \frac{1}{3} \leq \frac{n - n_{f(n)}}{\ell_{f(k)}} < \frac{2}{3}  \\
3 & \mbox{ if }\,\, \frac{2}{3} \leq \frac{n - n_{f(n)}}{\ell_{f(k)}} < 1 
\end{cases}
$$